# Is there a way to create an auto-responder in Google Apps without creating a new user?

Tags: google-workspace

I have been using cpanel until now to manage my email and I find it much easier then Google Apps. How can I get it that when someone emails info@domain.com an auto-responder goes out to the author saying that someone will be in touch.

Do i have to make a new User and set it from the personal settings on the Gmail page? What happens when I have these fake email addresses in bulk?

Explanation: When I create a email-alias/nickname for info@domain to go to me@domain.com there is no User of info. So how can I do an autoresponder

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are two ways.

**Easiest but limited**

1. create the alias for your user
2. in Labs enable Canned Responses
3. create the Canned Response you want to send to people who email info@domain.com
4. create a filter for all email sent to info@domain.com, one of the choices will be to send a Canned Response

This is quick and simple to setup. However, the downside is it will come from your main email address. If you create the info@domain.com user account and follow the same directions, it will reply from info@domain.com.

Also, depending on the volume of email, you might hit a ceiling for sending email. Free accounts are 500 per day and paid are 2000 per day.

**More flexible but also more difficult**

Create an alias info@domain.com and then build a Google Apps Script auto-responder. It could come from info@domain.com and you could build more complex handling too (eg forward to different people depending on subject line). It is beyond the scope of Web Applications to explain in more detail but you can find help in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do that with groups (https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain.com/CPanelHome#GroupListSettings), which lets you "forward" emails sent there to any emails under your domain. You might even be able to set up an auto-responder in your Gmail.

If not, you could use Zapier and use a Zap that [Triggers an Outbound Email from an Inbound Email](https://zapier.com/z/ChI/zapbook/gmail/gmail/2570/email-from-new-gmail-email/), just remember to set up a filter to only act of emails from that particular group (IE: "to:group@your-domain.com").

Comment: a group would be the same as a nickname (alias) in that it would deliver mail to a prescribed mailbox.

Comment: Can Zapier use a different send-as account in a Gmail or Google Apps account? If not, he will need to create a second account.

Answer (score -1):

Enter your mailbox in browser, then Configuration - Settings.
There you will find a Vacation Responder

It has a range date and fields to set the autoresponder email

Answer (score -2):

You Cant ,You Must Create a Google Account
Just Go To  
then register or if you allready have an account then LOGIN